# EF6 : AddRange throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use AddRange method to create a bulk insert into my DB.

This is what I do :

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<E> InsertRange(IEnumerable<E> entities)
    {
        Context.Set<E>().AddRange(entities);

        if (isAutoSave)
            Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I call SaveChanges() I get an exception saying:

```
Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.
```

I think the problem might be in my model. My Id column, which is a PK and Identity is of type int, which cause all the new entities to be with Id=0. What can I do to solve that?

Thanks,
Matan

Comment: How did you produce the error message you show?

Comment: If they are new objects that don't exist in the database, the `Id` of each object should be zero. This informs Entity Framework that these objects are new and that they need to be assigned a non-zero ID when inserted into the database. I suspect there may be a different issue with your model. Can you please provide the code for the class of the objects you're trying to insert?

Comment: don't know how we should add more to the (very good) error-message you get

Comment: Please check the constraints on your table. Maybe there is a unique constraint to another column

Comment: The are four foreign keys on that table. And they all seem to be fine. the model holds an Id property, and four other int properties that are foreign keys to other tables.

Comment: Are you using db first or code first? Are you sure the id in the table is set as auto incremental?

Comment: I am using db first, I am sure the id column is set as AI, i double checked it and i also see it in my model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to disable ef tracking - do whatever you need, save changes and enable it back. That will also increase performance of your insert operation.

So, before calling method which will insert and save changes just add this:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

And when you are done enable it back:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am already doing that for preformance, I keep getting the same error

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you getting this on every entity type or just particular one. If it's related to only one entity type then it could be that FK are causing errors, but anyway if you provide more code it's easier to understand what is actually happening..

Comment: I haven't tried to do it with more entity types, as this is the first time i have the need to do that. anyway the code is from a generic DAL repository I created, I will provide some more code soon